# How can I keep the links from a JSON in a TextView?

Tags: android, json, hyperlink, textview, href

I'm collecting information from a JSON website and displaying it in my Android app as a TextView. The information is taken from a standard MySQL database and stripped of tags (with php).

What I want to do is keep the links in the texts. E.g. "For more information, click *here*", here is not a click-able link.

I tried keeping the " < a > " tags when stripping but that didn't get the desired effect in the app either.

Any suggestion of where to look next would be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in TextView

```
 android:autoLink="all"
```

and add this line to your textview

```
t3.setText(
        Html.fromHtml(
            "<b>text3:</b>  Text with a " +
            "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> " +
            "created in the Java source code using HTML."));
    t3.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

visit [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/text/Link.html) for more .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're removing the html tags yourself but; even if they're not stripped out of the returned json you can do this:

```
String fromHTML = "blah blah blah <a href='www.google.com'>Google</a>";
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(description));
```

-serkan

Comment: Hmm...all tags are stripped on the php end of things. I'm stripping everything except <a href's> and when adding the text to the TextView it comes out like this "<a href='www.google.com'> google </a>". Literally like that, unfortunately...

Comment: That's interesting Eugen, I just tried my own code :) but the link renders just fine as a TextView.  I'm not sure if there is a difference in API or device at this point???

Comment: You're right, my apologies. The source text I was getting was off. Sorry for messing things up and thanks a lot for taking your time to help me! I hope you don't mind if I pick sunny's answer though. It's more general and the Html.fromHtml function will help me a lot. Thanks again.